# Play/Slick: SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1001ms of waiting for a connection

Tags: postgresql, playframework, slick, playframework-2.4, play-slick

I've created an empty (activator template play-scala) Play 2.4.3 application with PostgreSQL 9.4 database and trying to use Slick 3.1.0 with it, but it's throwing an error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:165) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12) ~[slick-hikaricp_2.11-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:57) ~[play-slick-evolutions_2.11-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:60) ~[play-slick-evolutions_2.11-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:119) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:97) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:112) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:77) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:50) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:98) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:49) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:149) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44) ~[play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.scala:98) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:438) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

This is my build.sbt:

```
name := """et"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    cache,
    ws,
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1",
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1205-jdbc42"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

and application.conf:

```
play.evolutions.db.default.enabled = true

slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
slick.dbs.default.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.default.password = "postgres"
```

Everything should be fine according to the documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick), so what could be wrong here?

**UPDATE:** One important thing I've noticed - I have a single database evolution and as soon as I removed it - the error is gone. I do need evolutions though, so the problem is still there.

**UPDATE2:** So I found some relevant issues on github, yet no resolution:
https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/275
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4675

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in configuration, this is a working example:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "postgres"
```

Comment: We're having the same problem (exactly the same version of Play, Slick and Postgres) when we run our Play app in ECS in AWS connecting to a Postgres RDS instance. When we run the app locally (connecting to the same RDS instance) everything works fine! Any ideas? If we disable evolutions, it works fine though both locally and on AWS.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue with Play 2.5.9 and Slick 3.11. I resolved it by adding slick.dbs.default.db.properties.url:

```
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:<port>/<db>"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.url="jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:<port>/<db>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you entered incorrect login details it will still come back as a timeout not as an Auth error or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the timeout worked for me.

```
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTimeout = 5000
```